# Trying to get a result array of strings instead of ids

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi im trying to get the following results

Table1

```
ID | Name
 1 | Name1
 2 | Name2
```

Table2

```
ID | State | NameIDS
 1 | NY    | 1,2
 2 | ZA    | 1
```

I am trying to joun by th entire array so i get

```
ID | State | NameIDS
 1 | NY    | Name1,Name2
 2 | ZA    | Name1
```

trying to get this in a single query ive tried

```
Select Table2.ID,State,Table1.Name 
From Table2 
    JOIN Table1 ON FIND_IN_SET(Table1.ID, Table2.NameIDS) != 0
```

But this gives me

```
   ID | State | NameIDS
    1 | NY    | Name1
    1 | NY    | Name2
    2 | ZA    | Name1
```

Comment: Is it too late to fix the database design error that has a comma delimited list in a single field on a database row?

Comment: ya DB has already been implemented this way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix your data model!  You should not be stored multiple ids in a string list.  Here are some good reasons why:

- Numbers should be stored as numbers, not *strings*.
- Columns should contain only one value.
- Databases are not very good or efficient at string functions.
- Ids should be declared with proper, foreign key relationships.
- Databases have this great structure for storing lists.  It is called a *table*!

Sometimes, you are stuck with other peoples really, really, really, really, really bad data modeling decisions.  If that is the case, you can do:

```
select t2.ID, t2.State,
       group_concat(t1.Name order by t1.id) as names
from Table2 t2 join
     Table1 t1
     on find_in_set(t1.ID, t2.NameIDS) <> 0
group by t2.ID, t2.State;
```